# Accessing state of bloc in different view where app is using onGenerateRoute

Tags: flutter, bloc

Context:
I want to share Language across entire app. Due to that I want to have single instance of `LanguageBloc` which I can access across application to retrieve it's state which is `LanguageModel`

Problem:
How to solve dependencies?
Because I am using `onGenerateRoute` I don't know how to make one instance BlocProvider from `LanguageBloc` that can be accessed in different screen. I noticed I am creating each time new instance and of course new instance has no knowledge of `LanguageBloc`

Code:

main

```
void main() {
  runApp(App(Routes()));
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Routes routes;

  const App(this.routes, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'test',
      onGenerateRoute: routes.onGenerateRoute,
      home: RepositoryProvider(
        create: (context) => LanguageService(),
        child: InitialScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
      ),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: kPrimary,
        textTheme: kTextTheme,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Route

```
class Routes {
  Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case RoutesNames.initialScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => InitialScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
        );
      case RoutesNames.welcomeScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => RepositoryProvider(
            create: (context) => UserService(),
            child: WelcomeScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
          ),
        );
      case RoutesNames.privacyPolicyScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => PrivacyPolicyScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
        );
      case RoutesNames.termsAndConditionsScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => TermsAndConditionScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
        );
      case RoutesNames.homeScreen:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => HomeScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
        );
      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (_) => WelcomeScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
        );
    }
  }
}
```

InitialScreen

```
class InitialScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const InitialScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => LanguageBloc(
        languageService: RepositoryProvider.of<LanguageService>(context),
      )..add(const LanguageInitialEvent()),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: InitialScreenView(
          key: UniqueKey(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class InitialScreenView extends StatelessWidget {
  const InitialScreenView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<LanguageBloc, LanguageState>(
      builder: (builderContext, state) {
        if (state is LanguageSuccessfulState) {
          SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
            Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, RoutesNames.welcomeScreen);
          });
        }
      },
    );
```

WelcomeScreen

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  WelcomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => EnterBloc(
        userService: RepositoryProvider.of<UserService>(context),
      )..add(const EnterInitialEvent()),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: WelcomeScreenView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WelcomeScreenView extends StatelessWidget {
  WelcomeScreenView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<EnterBloc, EnterState>(
      builder: (builderContext, state) {
        //...
      }
    );
```

Question:
How in `WelcomeScreenView.build` I can access `LanguageState`?

What I have tried:

- I tried using `MultiBlocProvider` in front of MaterialApp so I would create only one instance. Sadly that gives null value and it cannot show first screen
- I tried using `context.select<LanguageBloc, LanguageModel?>((LanguageBloc bloc)` but first it was giving me null value, but later after a lot of tweaking it gave me `Not registed` this is probably because I create new instance
- this is what I want to achieve and I tried make my solution based on this [How to use bloc pattern between two screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59633438/how-to-use-bloc-pattern-between-two-screens) so I removed `BlocProvider` in `WelcomeScreen` and also in `InitialScreen`. I made `MultiBlocProvider` in App and register there `LanguageBloc` and `EnterBloc` but this gives me `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'LanguageBloc' in type cast`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `repository` to the first level and on the second level place the `MultiBlocProvider`, to not have other bloc instances, remove the `bloc create` and `repository create` from the screens and keep only the `blocBuilder`. With this, both repositories and blocs will be available in the context of the entire application.

```
class App extends StatelessWidget {
  final Routes routes;

  const App(this.routes, {super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider<LanguageService>(
          create: (context) => LanguageService(),
        ),
        RepositoryProvider<UserService>(
          create: (context) => UserService(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<LanguageBloc>(
              create: (context) => LanguageBloc(
                    languageService:
                        RepositoryProvider.of<LanguageService>(context),
                  )..add(const LanguageInitialEvent())),
          BlocProvider<EnterBloc>(
              create: (context) => EnterBloc(
                    userService: RepositoryProvider.of<UserService>(context),
                  )..add(const EnterInitialEvent())),
        ],
        child: MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'test',
          onGenerateRoute: routes.onGenerateRoute,
          home: InitialScreen(key: UniqueKey()),
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: kPrimary,
            textTheme: kTextTheme,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working fine :) Now I can do `context.select<LanguageBloc, LanguageModel?>((LanguageBloc bloc) { }` One more question. Would that mean that I need to register all services and blocs before MaterialApp? It feels bit like a code smell and performance loss

Comment: Yes, exactly that. You could also do it on demand, but that would involve creating singletons and services locator.